# Javascript function in Nunjucks

Tags: javascript, templating, nunjucks

So I've found this in the Nunjucks docs:

**Function Calls**

If you have passed a javascript method to your template, you can call it like normal.

```
{{ foo(1, 2, 3) }}
```

But I can't seem to make in work, I've tried putting my function on the html page in `<script>` tags but its not working.

I've also tried passing it with the data to the render function:

```
{
    stuff: function (string, length) {
        while (string < length) {
            string = "0" + string
        }
    }
}
```

And I get: unable to call `data["stuff"], which is undefined of falsey`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `addGlobal` (see `g`) or pass a function to render (see `f`).

```
var nunjucks  = require('nunjucks');
var env = nunjucks.configure();

function f (s) {
    return s + s; 
}

function g (s) {
    return s + s + s; 
}

env.addGlobal('g', g);

var res = nunjucks.renderString('{{f("OK")}} {{g("ok")}}', {f: f});    
console.log(res);

//Output: OKOK okokok
```