# Can i get full url from Nunjucks template engine?

Tags: javascript, nunjucks

I try to get full url from Nunjucks but i did not find any solution. I can get this url using javascript code but how can i use this code in Nunjucks ?

This is javascript code

```
let url = window.location.href;

let referral_link= ""
if(url.indexOf('?su=') != -1){
  let format_link = url.split("?su=");
  referral_link = "?su="+format_link[1]
}
```

When i add console then get valid text
I need to use this value in Nunjucks

something like this

```
{% set sectionHeader = { title: referral_link } %}
```

or i possible to get full url using Nunjucks code

It will be very helpfull

Comment: Just add a `global` function. Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51788055/javascript-function-in-nunjucks/51797890#51797890).

Comment: Are you using gulp and browser-sync to help run your nunjucks project?